# Creation Dynamic checkboxes Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I've got an issue that I don't understand.

I'm creating a "generator" of checkboxes based on an array.

```js
   var array = new Array();
   array[0]="Monday";
   array[1]="Tuesday";
   array[2]="Wendesday";
   array[3]="Thirsday";
   array[4]="Friday";
   array[5]="Saturday";
   array[6]="Sunday";

   var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
      var val = '';
      var cap = '';
      var cb = document.createElement('input');

      var j = "";
   for (var i in array) {
    //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
    j = i.toString();
    console.log('J = ', j);
    val = j;
    //cap will be the value/text of array[i]
    cap = array[i];
    console.log('cap =', cap);


       cb.type = 'checkbox';
       cbh.appendChild(cb);
       cb.name = val;
       cb.value = cap;
       cbh.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cap));
   }
```

```css
   * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   #data {
       padding:0;
    width:100vw;
   }
   .multiselect {
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:1px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:100vw;
    white-space: normal;
    height:200px;
   }
   .checkboxes {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:-1px;
    display:inline-block;
   }
  </style>
```

```html
<form>
   <div id="data">
    <div class="multiselect">
      <div id="checkboxes">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
```

(the CSS is not important for my problem... I think)

The problem is that it creates only one checkboxe, for the last element and I don't understand why... I would like a checkboxe for each day.

After that I'm asking how to retrieve the element select, but this is in a second part.

So If someone has an idea, I would be thanksfull !

regards.

Comment: You dont need j=i.toString() . Whenever you do "somestring"+i , the engine is doing this for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var cb = document.createElement('input');` use this line inside for loop

```js
var array = new Array();
   array[0]="Monday";
   array[1]="Tuesday";
   array[2]="Wendesday";
   array[3]="Thirsday";
   array[4]="Friday";
   array[5]="Saturday";
   array[6]="Sunday";

   var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
      var val = '';
      var cap = '';
      

      var j = "";
   for (var i in array) {
    //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
    j = i.toString();
 
    val = j;
    //cap will be the value/text of array[i]
        var cb = document.createElement('input');
        var label= document.createElement("label");
        
       cap = array[i];
          var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
       cb.type = 'checkbox';
       cbh.appendChild(cb);
       cb.name = val;
       cb.value = cap;
          label.appendChild(cb); 
          label.appendChild(text);
       cbh.appendChild(label);
   }
```

```css
* {
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   #data {
       padding:0;
    width:100vw;
   }
   .multiselect {
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:1px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:100vw;
    white-space: normal;
    height:200px;
   }
   .checkboxes {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:-1px;
    display:inline-block;
   }
      
            label {
  display: inline-block;
}
  </style>
```

```html
<form>
   <div id="data">
    <div class="multiselect">
      <div id="checkboxes">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
```

Update : in order to keep label and checkbox together 
use

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer ! It works but When I narrow the window the checkbox ma be separated. (checkbox on a line, and his text on an other line). Do you have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: i updated my answer as per your requirement. check now.

Comment: @Carnatik i added css and label for each checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your new Node inside your for loop :

```js
var array = new Array();
   array[0]="Monday";
   array[1]="Tuesday";
   array[2]="Wendesday";
   array[3]="Thirsday";
   array[4]="Friday";
   array[5]="Saturday";
   array[6]="Sunday";

   var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
      

      var j = "";
   for (var i in array) {
              var val = '';
        var cap = '';
        var cb = document.createElement('input');
    //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
    j = i.toString();
    console.log('J = ', j);
    val = j;
    //cap will be the value/text of array[i]
    cap = array[i];
    console.log('cap =', cap);


       cb.type = 'checkbox';
       cbh.appendChild(cb);
       cb.name = val;
       cb.value = cap;
       cbh.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cap));
   }
```

```html
<form>
   <div id="data">
    <div class="multiselect">
      <div id="checkboxes">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer ! It works but When I narrow the window the checkbox ma be separated. (checkbox on a line, and his text on an other line). Do you have any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Put  var cb = document.createElement('input'); inside the loop:

```
                var j = "";
                for (var i in array) {
                    //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
                    var cb = document.createElement('input');
                    j = i.toString();
                    console.log('J = ', j);
                    val = j;
                    //cap will be the value/text of array[i]
                    cap = array[i];
                    console.log('cap =', cap);


                    cb.type = 'checkbox';
                    cbh.appendChild(cb);
                    cb.name = val;
                    cb.value = cap;
                    cbh.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cap));
                }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer ! It works but When I narrow the window the checkbox ma be separated. (checkbox on a line, and his text on an other line). Do you have any idea how to fix it ?